# GEE classification using RF on sentinel 2

Tags: classification, svm, random-forest, google-earth-engine

I am new to GEE and am struggling with getting classification results. I used the code below https://code.earthengine.google.com/41a8eecb7f430236d9d106ddfc866029

I don't know what am doing wrong. Can someone please assist with getting the classification results as well as all the tables.
Please explain like you are explaining to a two year old

I tried the export function